# Does Weblogic 8.1 work with MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, weblogic

Weblogic documentation indicates that version 8.1 of Weblogic Supports MS SQL 2000 and MS SQL 2005. Has anyone used weblogic 8.1 with MS SQL 2008 ? If so, any "ifs" and "buts" to be aware of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.2 of the Microsoft JDBC Driver can be used with Weblogic 8.1 to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database. This configuration isn't supported by Oracle/BEA, however, it does work.

A good source for some of the "buts" is Microsoft's JDBC team blog. An example post discussing using the new SQL 2008 data types is http://blogs.msdn.com/jdbcteam/archive/2008/09/28/working-with-sql-server-2008-date-time-data-types-using-v1-2-jdbc-driver.aspx